# How to create a Qt dialog with dynamic number of text inputs?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to make a form/dialog with a dynamic number of text input elements (e.g. Line Edit widget)? So the user can choose to "add another" item.

Comment: Can't you use a QTableWidget?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dialog with a layout. You could connect a slot to a button in the dialog that will add an item by retrieving the dialog layout and adding a new item.

so something like:

```
void MyDialog::on_addButton_clicked()
{
    QLayout *layout = layout();
    if (layout) {
        layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
    }
}
```

And if you give the items an unique name with: `setObjectName("someName")` you could later use `findChild<QLineEdit*>("someName");` to find all added line edits for further processing.

Comment: why should you retrieve the layout while your dialog is known a head? and have you tested  `layout` would retrieve anything especially if there are multiple ones?

Comment: @MohammadKanan You will need the layout to add items dynamically, so either you already have a pointer or you will retrieve it via the getter. Also there can only be 1 layout set for the dialog, so the getter will always return the correct one.

Comment: I think no geter in your example, `QLayout::count()` and `QLayout::itemAt()`

Comment: ah but you do not need that right?. I do not check the number of items already in the layout and so i do not use that to calculate the position of the widget you want to add. But i think the new widget will just be added at the end if you use addWidget().

Comment: thats not my point, I mean call to static `QLayout::count()` will bind to **existing** layout ..